# ValueError: Expecting , delimiter

Tags: python-2.7

I am stuck in a problem with this simple code, unable to debug the problem. when I ran the code it gave me this error.

> ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 4 column 4 (char 20)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   import json 
   input='''
[
{ "id":"001"
  "name":"nikhil"
  "x":'2'
},
{ "id":"002"
  "name":"chuck"
  "x":"2"
}
]'''

info=json.loads(input)
print "User count:",len(info)

for item in info:

    print "Name",item("name")
    print "id",item("id")
    print "Attribute",item("x")
```

Comment: json objects need to have commas between each key:value pair.

Comment: yes you were right that was the problem.Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error in my code was that I hadn't separated the 'key:value' pairs by a comma. I added the commas and indented the code properly an it worked,

Answer (score 0):

**need commas**

```
import json 
#here after "id" : "001" we have ,
    input='''
    [
    { "id":"001",
      "name":"nikhil",
      "x":'2'
    },
    { "id":"002",
      "name":"chuck",
      "x":"2"
    }
    ]'''

    info=json.loads(input)
    print "User count:",len(info)

    for item in info:

        print "Name",item("name")
        print "id",item("id")
        print "Attribute",item("x")
```